# DBXML Error centos 5.5(64bit) and php 5.2

Tags: php, xml, linux

I have installed dbxml and db4 in my server running with CentOS 5.5(64 bit) and php 5.2

I am getting some waring messages in my site.

> Warning: db4env::open() [db4env.open]: (null) Build signature doesn't match environment in /var/www/html/modules/lib/class.bdbxml.php on line 135
>   Warning: db4env::open() [db4env.open]: open(bdb, 0, 0) failed: Operation not permitted (1) /usr/local/src/dbxml-2.5.16/db-4.8.26/php_db4/db4.cpp:1937 in /var/www/html/modules/lib/class.bdbxml.php

Can anybody help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

SELinux may be the problem. Is it disabled?

Answer (score 0):

In Berkeley DB "Build signature doesn't match environment" error is most commonly associated with opening an Berkeley DB environment that was created with a different architecture.

e.g. a 32-bit environment on a 64-bit machine or vice versa.